# Setting Sort Direction on Column Click for ASP.NET Telerik MVC Grid Column

Tags: sorting, telerik, grid, telerik-mvc

Currently using the Telerik MVC 3.0 in Asp.net. I Have grid with few Columns.
When the pageloads the rows are binded. When i click on the column it should sort in Descending sorder in the first Click instead of Ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by overwritting grid's toggleOrder method.
First, define a new ReverseToggleOrder function:

```
function ReverseToggleOrder(l) {

    l = typeof l == "number" ? this.columns[l] : l;
    var n = "desc";
    if (l.order == "desc") {
        n = "asc";
    } else {
        if (l.order == "asc") {
            n = null;
        }
    }
    l.order = n;
    var m = $.inArray(l, this.sorted);
    if (this.sortMode == "single" && m < 0) {
        $.each(this.sorted, function () {
            this.order = null;
        });
        this.sorted = [];
    }
    if (m < 0 && n) {
        this.sorted.push(l);
    }
    if (!n) {
        this.sorted.splice(m, 1);
    }
}


function grid_onLoad(e) {

    var grid = $(this).data('tGrid');
    grid.toggleOrder = ReverseToggleOrder;
}
```

Then in grid's OnLoad event handler you need to overwrite its default behaviour:

.ClientEvents(events => events.OnLoad("grid_onLoad"))

Answer (score 0):

The Grid does not support such sorting configuration. It always sorts ASC then DESC.